# "Call to undefined method Closure::authenticate()" in dingo-API

Tags: laravel-5, dingo-api

"message": "Call to undefined method Closure::authenticate()",
    "code": 1,
    "status_code": 500,

Comment: Can you show some code and how are you calling this?

Comment: thanks but got the solution

Comment: Would be a big help to people to tell how you got the solution.